# Add tag list to wordpress rss

Tags: wordpress, rss, tags

How can i add a post's tags list to the wordpress rss feed? I have modified my feed-rss.php to export the author and the pubblication date, but i can't find a function to insert in the rss even the tags list for each post exported.

```
<?php
/**
 * RSS 0.92 Feed Template for displaying RSS 0.92 Posts feed.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

header('Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type('rss-http') . '; charset=' .     get_option('blog_charset'), true);
$more = 1;

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>'; ?>
<rss version="0.92">
<channel>
    <title><?php bloginfo_rss('name'); wp_title_rss(); ?></title>
    <link><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></link>
    <description><?php bloginfo_rss('description') ?></description>
    <lastBuildDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000',     get_lastpostmodified('GMT'), false); ?></lastBuildDate>
    <docs>http://backend.userland.com/rss092</docs>
    <language><?php echo get_option('rss_language'); ?></language>
    <?php do_action('rss_head'); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<item>
    <dc:creator><?php the_author() ?></dc:creator>
    <title><?php the_title_rss() ?></title>
    <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></description>
    <link><?php the_permalink_rss() ?></link>
    <?php do_action('rss_item'); ?>
    <pubDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), false); ?></pubDate>
    <tags><?php echo the_tags(); ?></tags>
</item>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a function in the RSS to get the Tags alone, since all the tags are showed as the Categories.

Try loading the tags using the wp_get_post_tags method and add them inside the  tag.